# Simple WebAPI path works in localhost but not in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have created a very simple 4.6.1 WebApi which returns a list of JSON.

The below code works in localhost with a path of

http://localhost:62093/api/products

```
 public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[]
       {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
       };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }
```

I then use the Publish feature and move the web.config, global.asax and Bin folder onto my IIS 8.5 server into a subfolder with this path

e:\www\apis\fct\hl

[image: Application in IIS]

If I attempt to access the webapi at path

http://servername/fct/hl/api/products it simply returns a 404.

I'm at a loss at this point.

Comment: `hl` is a folder, not an application.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not sure what to do with that comment..are you saying that HL needs to also be an application, or not reffered to in the path?  Unclear.  Thx

Comment: Convert it to an application and see if that works.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Thx, I made hl into an application also and now it works.